# Spring doesn't use h2 databases for testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, h2

I have a small database application running on mySQL.

I want to use the H2 for testing.

I added the necessary dependency to build.gradle:

runtimeOnly 'com.h2database: h2'

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group = 'com.myprojects'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

However, I noticed that after doing the tests, my mySQL database contains the fields generated during the tests, as if spring was not using H2.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Spring Boot with Gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) (what I can assume from your posted `build.gradle` file) & want strictly seperate test environment & production/development, you have to add a new `application.properties` in your `test/resources` directory.
This application file will then be used, in your test environment.

[image]

**ATTENTION:** Every necessary entry that is not present in this file, will fall back to the property file in your `src` directory. This can lead to some inconsitencies in your application setup.

**--- The following part does also work with none Gradle builds: ---**

If you want to use a specific property in a specific test, you can use the [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-testpropertysource) annotation.

With this you can now define a default properties for the majority of your tests & speceific properties for specific tests, meaning the `@TestPropertySource` annotations are of higher order than the `application.properties` in the test directory & overwrite them.

Answer (score 1):

You need configure the application.properties / yaml, like that:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dbtest
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

You can see more here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database